How does integrating this integral containing the digamma function result in 2 ln?

How does the constant of 1/4 become 2? when they integrate the digamma function, what is happening?
The original question on Quora

Please don't use images.

Would you be able to help me? after integration, i cant figure out how 1/4 becomes 2!

The $1/4$ becomes $2$ because of the $8$ in the denominators inside the $\psi$'s, i.e.
if $$ \int \psi(t) \; dt = \ln \Gamma(t) + c$$ a change of variables $(-x+k)/8 = t$ gives you
$$ \eqalign{\int \psi\left(\frac{-x+k}{8}\right) \; dx &= -8 \int \psi(t)\; dt \cr&= -8 \ln \Gamma(t) + c = -8\ln \Gamma\left(\frac{-x+k}{8} \right) + c}$$
Actually I think the tricky part that is glossed over here is dealing with the limit as $x \to -\infty$ (using Stirling's approximation)

You are the man. I was at a loss all day on this one. Thank you Robert.
